# Matching values without to rewrite a very extensive query more than once SAP HANA

Tags: sql, performance, hana

I'm racking my brain over this little problem.

I have a very large query B which generates a Table B.

A query A that generates a list of customers Table A.

Both tables share "FACILITY" but the Neighborhoods values are not necessarily the same.

I need to join table B to Table A but I need to create a CONDITION column, Value 1 if NEIGHBORHOOD_A is found in NEIGHBORHOOD_B (even if FACILITY is not equal in Table B).

My dilemma is that Query B is very large and the way I can think of to generate a list is to rewrite query B, I think there must be some function that allows me to do this easily in a select statement like this:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER,
    A.FACILITY,
    B.FACILITY,
    NEIGHBORHOOD_A,
    NEIGHBORHOOD_B
    --Function that allows me to put a 1 if NEIGHBORHOOD_A is within any of the values of NEIGHBORHOOD_B
FROM
    (query_A) A
LEFT JOIN 
    (query_B) B ON A.FACILITY = B.FACILITY
```

Table A

| CUSTOMER | FACILTY | NEIGHBORHOOD_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | N1 |
| 2 | B | N2 |
| 3 | C | N3 |
| 4 | D | N1 |
| 5 | E | N4 |
| 6 | F | N5 |

Table B  (The sub Query that generates this table is very long and I don't want to have to rewrite it to generate a list of neighborhoods)

| FACILITY | NEIGHBORHOOD_B |
| --- | --- |
| A | N3 |
| B | N2 |
| C | N3 |
| F | N1 |
| Z | N4 |

Desired result

| Customer | FACILITY | NEIGHBORHOOD_A | NEIGHBORHOOD_B | CONDITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | N1 | N3 | 1 |
| 2 | B | N2 | N2 | 1 |
| 3 | C | N3 | N3 | 1 |
| 4 | D | N1 | NULL | 1 |
| 5 | E | N4 | NULL | 1 |
| 6 | F | N5 | N1 | 0 |

Comment: What DBMS are you using? 
Can you save Query B's results to a temp table or at least move it to a CTE? Then your Condition column would be a simple WHERE EXISTS calculation

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the solution is probably not as sophisticated as you may think.

**Data Sample**

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (customer integer, facility varchar(1), neighborhood_a varchar(2));
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1, 'A', 'N1');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (2, 'B', 'N2');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (3, 'C', 'N3');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (4, 'D', 'N1');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (5, 'E', 'N4');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (6, 'F', 'N5');


CREATE TABLE table_b (facility varchar(1), neighborhood_b varchar(2));
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('A', 'N3');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('B', 'N2');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('C', 'N3');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('F', 'N1');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES ('Z', 'N4');
```

**Query with sub-select in projection**

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN neighborhood_a IN (SELECT DISTINCT neighborhood_b FROM table_b) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cond
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.facility = b.facility 
ORDER BY a.customer, a.facility
```

**You can also solve this via join**

```
WITH neighborhoods AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT neighborhood_b FROM table_b
)
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN n.neighborhood_b IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS cond
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.facility = b.facility 
LEFT JOIN neighborhoods n ON a.neighborhood_a = n.neighborhood_b
ORDER BY a.customer, a.facility
```

In any case, please note that your `condition` field is independent from the original join with `table_b`, that you have proposed. So, if you don't need the information, that has been joined by `facility` and if it was just part of your anticipated solution, you may also remove this part to simplify the statement.

**Simplified version with projection**

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN neighborhood_a IN (SELECT DISTINCT neighborhood_b FROM table_b) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cond
FROM table_a a
ORDER BY a.customer, a.facility
```

**Simplified version with join**

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN b.neighborhood_b IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS cond
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT neighborhood_b FROM table_b) b 
    ON a.neighborhood_a = b.neighborhood_b
ORDER BY a.customer, a.facility
```

**Result**
[image]

Of course, you will have to replace `table_a` and `table_b` with your respective sub-selects. Also, since I do not know the sub-selects, I am not able to evaluate if these statements make sense from a performance perspective. Functionally, it should do the job.